# how can I get whole documents of duplicate records in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to get all fields of document using pymongo.
but getting only group by fields.
I want all documents with all fields.

```
collection.aggregate([
  {"$group": {
    "_id": {"des": "$Descreption", "price": "$NewPrice"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}
  },
  {"$match": {"_id" :{ "$ne" : "null" } , "count" : {"$gt": 1} } },
  {"$project": {"Descreption" : "$_id", "_id" : 0} }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$push` with `$$ROOT` for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {des: "$Descreption", price: "$NewPrice"},
      count: {$sum: 1},
      data: {$push: "$$ROOT"} // add this line
    }
  },
  {$match: {_id: {$ne: "null"}, count: {$gt: 1}}},
  {$project: {
      Descreption: "$_id",
      data: 1, // add this line
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WAVQXhgNM0C)

Comment: is there any way to sort this documents with any field?

Comment: Sure you can sort. Just sort before the `$group`